# Fortran Print Statements Performance Effects

Tags: fortran, stdout

I just inherited some old Fortran code that has print statements everywhere (when it runs, the matrix streams by). I know these print statements are useless because I cannot tell what the program is printing as it is going by so fast. But is there a significant performance impact to having a lot of print statements in a Fortran program (i.e. does an overly verbose program take longer to execute)? It seems like it would as it is another line to execute, but I don't know if it is significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes, I/O is "relatively costly" to execute since you have to do things like formatting numbers - especially floating point numbers, even if those procedures are highly optimized. However, one of the biggest costs (the system call to actually perform the I/O after the buffer to write has been prepared) is amortized in good compilers/runtimes since the I/O statements are usually buffered by default. This helps cut down the number of system calls significantly, thus reducing delays caused by frequent context switching between your app and the OS.

That said, if you are worried about the performance hit, why don't you try to comment every PRINT or WRITE statement and see how the runtime changes? Or even better, profile your application and see the amount of time spent on I/O and related routines.

Comment: In gfortran, it is somehow buffered, but with limits. You can place a print statement before a line with crash and you can be sure the print gets finished and really displayed before the crash happens. If there ate too many of these statements it does slow the code in my experience. Even by factors of magnitude if one starts to display large arrays repeatedly.